# Android Studio can't run my APP (<no module>)

Tags: module, android-studio

I did import a Eclipse project to Android Studio.

However, I can't execute my APP because I have only  in Android Application.
It appears in Android Test, but I am not able to select the module in Android Application.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of posting the answer as an update, you really should post the answer and accept it.  Questions should always stay as strictly questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting your update I removed from your question as an answer:

> It was really a BUG solved in latest SDK Eclipse and AS updates.